# Specifying the initial context factory to use in CXF

Tags: testing, jax-rs, cxf, jndi

I am using CXF Local Tranport for testing, following this tutorial:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAXRS+Testing

But I get this error: ***javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial***

This is a piece of code I have tried when I create my local server:

```
private static void startServer() throws Exception {
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();

    factory.setAddress(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);

    List<Class<?>> resourceClasses = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    // ..
    factory.setResourceClasses(resourceClasses);
    List<ResourceProvider> resourceProviders = new ArrayList<>();
    // ..
    factory.setResourceProviders(resourceProviders);

    final Hashtable<String, Object> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");

    final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
    providers.add(context);
    // ..
    factory.setProviders(providers);

    server = factory.create();
    server.start();
}
```

But it does not work.

I test jax-rs web services with WebClient (see tutorial), but it throws the exception maybe when the server launch this code:
// web service method

```
javax.naming.Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
TMM tmm = (TMM) initialContext.lookup("java:app/cos/TMM");
```

Comment: why are you using jndi? it's not in the wiki example, is it?